# When a Build Step fails in a team city build can I stop future build steps?

Tags: teamcity

I am using TeamCity as my CI server.

I have defined three Build Steps. One builds my project from the .sln file, one runs tests using MSTest the final one packages up some of the dlls and exes the project produces into a deployment package.

Currently even if some tests fail the deployment package is still created. How can I stop Team City from processing further Build Steps if one has a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I am not the only one with this problem.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-12194

I am not sure how to adjust my scripts to know if things upstream have failed.

Answer (score 2):

In the build conficguration genneral settings page, there is "Fail build if" section.

There is a checkbox in it which says "at least one test fails".

Is it checked?

[image: Build configuration sample]

Comment: It is checked and does not seem to make any difference :(